# How to pass the one of the function parameter to store class in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs4

In the one of the window i pass the search type as a parameter. After that i get the search type in the **mcmFindCityPair** and pass along with the **mcmFocusMarketStore** store. I need to pass the search type in the store called.**mcmFocusMarketStore**. I passed in store but it says the searchType is not defined. Can anyone help me to reorganize the code.
the snippet are:

window.js
here is the code...

```
App.mcmFindCityPair(this.mcmSearchType, this.mcmOriginTextbox.getValue(),
                    this.mcmDestinationTextbox.getValue(),this.mcmStartDateTimeField.getValue(), 
                    this.mcmEndDateTimeField.getValue());
```

app.js
here is the code

```
mcmFindCityPair : function(searchType, org, dest, start, end) {
        App.mcmFocusMarketStore.removeAll(true);
        var startDate = start ? Ext.Date.format(start, 'd-M-y H:i') : '';
        var endDate = end ? Ext.Date.format(end, 'd-M-y H:i') : '';
        console.log(searchType);
        App.mcmFocusMarketStore.proxy.url = getProxyUrl()
                + "&action=getFMFlights&searchType="+searchType
                + ("&origin=" + org)
                + ("&destination=" + dest)
                + (startDate ? ("&startDate=" + startDate) : '')
                + (endDate ? ("&endDate=" + endDate) : '');
        console.log(App.mcmFocusMarketStore.proxy.url);
        App.mcmFocusMarketStore.load();
        App.mcmAllFocusMarketStore.removeAll(true);
        App.mcmAllFocusMarketStore.proxy.url = getProxyUrl()
                + "&action=getFMFlights&searchType="+searchType;
        App.mcmAllFocusMarketStore.load();
    }



App.mcmFocusMarketStore = Ext.create(
                    'Ext.data.Store',
                    {
                        model : 'FocusMarketModel',
                        proxy : {
                            timeout : AJAX_TIMEOUT,
                            type : 'jsonp',
                            url : getProxyUrl()
                                    + "&action=getFMFlights&searchType="+ searchType,
                            reader : {
                                type : 'focusmarketReader',
                                root : 'success',
                                totalProperty : 'total'
                            },
                            listeners : {
                                exception : function(proxy, exception,
                                        operation) {
                                    alert('Failed to get any kind of response from server! The application will be restarted. ');

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Can anyone help me to reorganize the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks fine as long as `this.mcmSearchType` is fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny No this.mcmSearchType is in different js file. i just pass it to anther function which is main.js. in that i load it in store as query string.

Comment: Arun P Johny No this.mcmSearchType is in different js file. i just pass it to anther function which is main.js. in that i load it in store as query string.